# Measuring SNR to detect jammers in Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wifi, denial-of-service, wireless

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect a Wi-Fi 2.4 GHz signal Jammer. I am not looking into 
locating the location of the jammer but rather detect the jamming signal. How do i do so using 
only wireless adapters? 
How can i measure SNR, wouldn't that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just like to detect those jammers - SNR can be measured with tools like kismet, netstumbler, vistumbler.

But keep in mind:

- Other WiFi channels will be in your SNR analysis.
- A jammer is not the only way to take down a wifi network ;-)

Comment: Your are correct, however i was able to distinctively find the Jamming signal. I also just got a spectrum analyzer.
I am studying attacks on all stack levels as well ;)